# Obtaining an access token from a NET Core hosted WebAssembly Blazor application

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, asp.net-identity, blazor, identityserver4

I'm trying to obtain an access token from the API so that calls can be made to protected API methods from my Xamarin application. However, I'm struggling to find a solution where I can obtain this access token programmatically. I've tried configuring IdentityServer to allow Client Credentials but it ends up causing issues with the already configured .NET identity authentication. Does anyone have a solution to this?

I've managed to obtain an access token using the following configuration in Postman:

[image]

I have a solution that consists of:

- NET Core hosted WASM Blazor App
- Xamarin.Forms (Android, iOS)

The NET Core hosted WASM blazor application was setup with individual account authentication scaffolded.

Comment: Postman should generate the equivalent C# code for you

Comment: @Jason Do you know how I can view the C# equivalent in Postman?

Comment: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: Appreciate the speedy response @Jason, Postman just gives the C# equivalent of attaching the bearer but it doesn't show the way to actually get the bearer token programmatically which is what I'm struggling with

Comment: Do you want to authenticate via username and password by code and obtain an access token as response? Using Identity Server. Right?

Comment: Yeah pretty much @NicolaBiada

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390530/how-to-get-access-token-from-identity-server-by-passing-username-and-password

Comment: Only problem with that solution is, when I add a new client to the existing IdentityServer that is already configured it stops the login on the blazor wasm app working @NicolaBiada

Comment: Do you use the solution from 20B2 ?

Comment: Are you adding users via your Xamarin app and trying to log into your Blazor app?

Comment: @GHDevOps no all user management has been scaffolded onto NET Core hosted Blazor Web Assembly application. I'm just trying to authenticate against the already configured API that comes with the NET Core hosted Blazor Web Assembly application through a login on my Xamarin App so I can make calls to protected API methods

Comment: @NicolaBiada yeah I tried that solution